# Precompiling assets failed - remote rejected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have been looking around trying to figure out why Heroku is not "accepting" my deployment and looking for help. I have not done anything significant just added bootstrap and some editing. My first deployment was a success but this next one failed. I read somewhere this is a bug so I added an src folder and made a index.js file. Ran yarn update, ran bundle install incase I needed to update something. looked at my babel.config.js but nothing stood out (I dont really know what to look for) Any help is greatly appreciated!

Error:

```
  [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 25.62s.
remote:        I, [2021-06-04T21:52:45.128952 #360]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5fa23b33/public/assets/application-43e83168d1536a5883821e3cc8ec1131ee502acb6d26a77dd45b93ad11dda098.css
remote:        I, [2021-06-04T21:52:45.129249 #360]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5fa23b33/public/assets/application-43e83168d1536a5883821e3cc8ec1131ee502acb6d26a77dd45b93ad11dda098.css.gz
remote:        I, [2021-06-04T21:52:45.129462 #360]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5fa23b33/public/assets/custom-91d5d37298ccb7c5bf6e028899e879468125e1aededc57df093f84b618cde2bd.css
remote:        I, [2021-06-04T21:52:45.129719 #360]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5fa23b33/public/assets/custom-91d5d37298ccb7c5bf6e028899e879468125e1aededc57df093f84b618cde2bd.css.gz
remote:        Compiling...
remote:        Compilation failed:
remote:        Though the "loose" option was set to "false" in your @babel/preset-env config, it will not be used for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods since the "loose" mode option was set to "true" for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties.
remote:        The "loose" option must be the same for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods and @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object (when they are enabled): you can silence this warning by explicitly adding
remote:         ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }]
remote:        to the "plugins" section of your Babel config.

remote:         ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }]
remote:        to the "plugins" section of your Babel config.
remote:        Though the "loose" option was set to "false" in your @babel/preset-env config, it will not be used for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods since the "loose" mode option was set to "true" for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties.
remote:        The "loose" option must be the same for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods and @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object (when they are enabled): you can silence this warning by explicitly adding
remote:         ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }]
remote:        to the "plugins" section of your Babel config.
remote:
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to afternoon-lf-49433.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/afternoon-lf-49433.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function(api) {   var validEnv = ['development', 'test', 'production']   var currentEnv = api.env()   var isDevelopmentEnv = api.env('development')   var isProductionEnv = api.env('production')   var isTestEnv = api.env('test')

  if (!validEnv.includes(currentEnv)) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please specify a valid `NODE_ENV` or ' +
        '`BABEL_ENV` environment variables. Valid values are "development", ' +
        '"test", and "production". Instead, received: ' +
        JSON.stringify(currentEnv) +
        '.'
    )   }

  return {
    presets: [
      isTestEnv && [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          targets: {
            node: 'current'
          }
        }
      ],
      (isProductionEnv || isDevelopmentEnv) && [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          forceAllTransforms: true,
          useBuiltIns: 'entry',
          corejs: 3,
          modules: false,
          exclude: ['transform-typeof-symbol']
        }
      ]
    ].filter(Boolean),
    plugins: [
      'babel-plugin-macros',
      '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
      isTestEnv && 'babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring',
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        {
          loose: true
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
        {
          useBuiltIns: true
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
        {
          helpers: false
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator',
        {
          async: false
        }
      ]
    ].filter(Boolean)   } }
```

Specials Controller

```
class SpecialsController <ApplicationController
    before_action :set_special, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    

    def show    
    end

    def index
        @specials = Special.all 
    end

    def new
        @special = Special.new
    end

    def edit    
    end

    def create
        @special = Special.new(special_params)
        if @special.save
            flash[:notice] = "Special was created successfully!" 
            redirect_to @special
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def update
        if @special.update(special_params)
            flash[:notice] = "Special was updated!"
            redirect_to @special
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @special.destroy
        redirect_to specials_path
    end

    def day_of_week
        t = Time.now
        t.strftime("%A")
    end

    helper_method :day_of_week

    private

    def set_special
        @special = Special.find(params[:id])
    end

    def special_params
        params.require(:special).permit(:day, :title, :description, :price)
    end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1 class="text-center mt-4 text-info">Specials for <%= day_of_week %></h1>

<div class= "container">
    <div class="row">
        <% @specials.each do |special| %>
            <div class="col-md-4 mt-4">
                <div class="card text-center shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <div class="card-body ">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><%= link_to special.title, special_path(special), class: "text-success" %></h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted font-italic">Applebees</h6>
                    <p class="card-text"><%= truncate(special.description, length: 50) %></p>

                  </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>


<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th colspan ="3">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @specials.each do |special| %>
            <tr>
            
                <td><%= special.day %></td>
                <td><%= special.title %></td>
                <td><%= special.description %></td>
                <td>$<%= special.price %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Show', special_path(special)%></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_special_path(special)%></td>
                <td><%= link_to "Delete", special_path(special), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"} %></td>
                    
            </tr>
            
        <% end%>
    </tbody>

</table>
<p>
    <%= link_to 'Add a Special', new_special_path %>
</p>
```

Gemfile

```
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.1.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.1.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.3.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.1.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.1.3.2)
      activejob (= 6.1.3.2)
      activerecord (= 6.1.3.2)
      activestorage (= 6.1.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.3.2)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.1.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.1.3.2)
      actionview (= 6.1.3.2)
      activejob (= 6.1.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.3.2)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.1.3.2)
      actionview (= 6.1.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.3.2)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.9)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.1.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.1.3.2)
      activerecord (= 6.1.3.2)
      activestorage (= 6.1.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.3.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.1.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.3.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.1.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.3.2)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.1.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.3.2)
    activerecord (6.1.3.2)
      activemodel (= 6.1.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.3.2)
    activestorage (6.1.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.1.3.2)
      activejob (= 6.1.3.2)
      activerecord (= 6.1.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.3.2)
      marcel (~> 1.0.0)
      mini_mime (~> 1.0.2)
    activesupport (6.1.3.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.7.5)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capybara (3.35.3)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.8)
    crass (1.0.6)
    erubi (1.10.0)
    ffi (1.15.1-x64-mingw32)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.8.10)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.11.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    loofah (2.9.1)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (1.0.1)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mini_mime (1.0.3)
    minitest (5.14.4)
    msgpack (1.4.2)
    nio4r (2.5.7)
    nokogiri (1.11.6-x64-mingw32)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    pg (1.2.3-x64-mingw32)
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    puma (5.3.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.5.2)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-mini-profiler (2.3.2)
      rack (>= 1.2.0)
    rack-proxy (0.7.0)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.1.3.2)
      actioncable (= 6.1.3.2)
      actionmailbox (= 6.1.3.2)
      actionmailer (= 6.1.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.1.3.2)
      actiontext (= 6.1.3.2)
      actionview (= 6.1.3.2)
      activejob (= 6.1.3.2)
      activemodel (= 6.1.3.2)
      activerecord (= 6.1.3.2)
      activestorage (= 6.1.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.3.2)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 6.1.3.2)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (6.1.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.1.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.3.2)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (~> 1.0)
    rake (13.0.3)
    regexp_parser (2.1.1)
    rubyzip (2.3.0)
    sass-rails (6.0.0)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    sassc (2.4.0-x64-mingw32)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    semantic_range (3.0.0)
    sprockets (4.0.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.4.2)
    thor (1.1.0)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    tzinfo-data (1.2021.1)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    web-console (4.1.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (4.6.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    webpacker (5.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 5.2)
      semantic_range (>= 2.3.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.4)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.4.2)

PLATFORMS
  x64-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (>= 1.4.4)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 3.26)
  jbuilder (~> 2.7)
  pg
  puma (~> 5.0)
  rack-mini-profiler (~> 2.0)
  rails (~> 6.1.3, >= 6.1.3.2)
  sass-rails (>= 6)
  selenium-webdriver
  sqlite3 (~> 1.4)
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  web-console (>= 4.1.0)
  webdrivers
  webpacker (~> 5.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.7.3p183

BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that `loose` is `false` for the preset-env and `true` for `plugin-proposal-class-properties`. I can see you have `"loose": true` for `plugin-proposal-class-properties` in your babel config for the `plugin-proposal-class-properties` config, maybe you can try to add `"loose": true` to the `preset-env` configuration too:

```js
      (isProductionEnv || isDevelopmentEnv) && [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          forceAllTransforms: true,
          useBuiltIns: 'entry',
          corejs: 3,
          modules: false,
          exclude: ['transform-typeof-symbol'],
          loose: true
        }
      ]
```

Comment: I never changed this before. Is it normal that I should change this or could this be because I incorrectly wrote a method?

Comment: It's not normal if you didn't change anything related to the assets, and it's also totally unrelated to a controller method change. Did you yarn.lock file change between deploys? does the deploy work if you deploy the previous version of the code that worked before? you have to compare the commit that works with the commit that doesn't to check for differences, it's impossible for us to know what changed since you are now showing a diff, just some current code. Maybe you did change something by mistake? you said you added bootstrap, then tried yarn update, it's not clear what changed